# Max Born's statistical interpretation of the wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

How did Max Born derive the probability of finding a particle between $x$ and  $x+dx$ at instant $t$?:

$$ \left |\psi(x,t)\right|^2dx$$

Was this result mathematically derived?  Or is it just a postulate, like the Schrödinger equation itself?

Comment: The quantity $q=e|\psi|^2$ is the charge density. Since charge is conserved and the distribution is positive definite this allows the interpretation of $q/e$ as a probability density. Also, the energy distribution for an eigenstart is proportional to $|\psi|^2$. Note that one cannot measure probability, only observables such as energy-momentum, charge-current and angular momentum (spin, orbital) can be measured.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is equivalent to the statement that $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ is the probability density function for the particle, because the definition of the probability density $p(x)$ is such that $p(x)dx$ is the probability of an event occurring between $x$ and $x+dx$.

The statement that $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ is the probability density function is known as the *Born rule*, and in most mainstream quantum mechanics interpretations, it's considered to be a fundamental postulate. Several lesser-known interpretations claim to be able to derive it or otherwise intuit it using statistical arguments (for example, quantum Bayesianism considers the Born rule to be an extension of the Law of Total Probability, and the hidden-measurements interpretation and pilot-wave theory both claim to be able to derive the Born rule from other axioms), but these use a different set of axioms than mainstream quantum-mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Wave Mechanics was heavily influenced by classical electromagnetic waves, and in classical EM, the intensity of a wave is proportional to the square of the field's strength.  Luckily, this turned out to be true in QM as well.

Comment: .... which simply begs the question: why should the intensity of the quantum wave matter?

Comment: The value of the wave or the intensity (the wave squared)?  The wave is all that exists, so it matters quite a bit.

Comment: You’re missing the gist of my comment, which is why would the intensity of the wave *in QM* be of interest when the wavefunction has properties so different from electromagnetic waves.